# How do I get the rows where a certain value occurs?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have `orders_df`:

```
       Symbol Order  Shares
Date                           
2011-01-10   AAPL   BUY    1500
2011-01-13   AAPL  SELL    1500
2011-01-13    IBM   BUY    4000
2011-01-26   GOOG   BUY    1000
2011-02-02    XOM  SELL    4000
2011-02-10    XOM   BUY    4000
2011-03-03   GOOG  SELL    1000
2011-03-03    IBM  SELL    2200
2011-05-03    IBM   BUY    1500
2011-06-03    IBM  SELL    3300
2011-08-01   GOOG   BUY      55
2011-08-01   GOOG  SELL      55
```

I want have a variable that maps `Date` to the number of `SELLS` on that date. I also want a symmetric variable for `BUY`.

I tried doing it for all `Orders` by doing

```
num_orders_per_day = orders_df.groupby(['Date']).size()
```

and got:

```
Date
2011-01-10    1
2011-01-13    2
2011-01-26    1
2011-02-02    1
2011-02-10    1
2011-03-03    2
2011-05-03    1
2011-06-03    1
2011-08-01    2
```

but that is not the desired output.

What I want is `sells_on_a_day`:

```
2011-01-13    1
2011-02-02    1
2011-03-03    2
2011-06-03    1
2011-08-01    1
```

and then a similar `buys_on_a_day` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then get `count`:

```
num_sells_per_day = orders_df[orders_df['Order'] == 'SELL']
                       .groupby(level=0).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (num_sells_per_day)
        Date  count
0 2011-01-13      1
1 2011-02-02      1
2 2011-03-03      2
3 2011-06-03      1
4 2011-08-01      1
```

Alternative:

```
num_sells_per_day = orders_df.query("Order == 'SELL'")
                             .groupby(level=0)
                             .size()
                             .reset_index(name='count')
print (num_sells_per_day)
        Date  count
0 2011-01-13      1
1 2011-02-02      1
2 2011-03-03      2
3 2011-06-03      1
4 2011-08-01      1
```

Also is possible create 2 columns together, only get `NaN`s if some values missing:

```
df1 = orders_df.groupby(['Date','Order']).size().unstack()
print (df1)
Order       BUY  SELL
Date                 
2011-01-10  1.0   NaN
2011-01-13  1.0   1.0
2011-01-26  1.0   NaN
2011-02-02  NaN   1.0
2011-02-10  1.0   NaN
2011-03-03  NaN   2.0
2011-05-03  1.0   NaN
2011-06-03  NaN   1.0
2011-08-01  1.0   1.0
```

Comment: I would change the name to `num_sells_per_day` for clarity, but it does work.